# Writing a shorter stream to a StorageFile

Tags: windows-runtime, xml-serialization, storagefile

I have a StorageFile that contains XML. I read the XML from the StorageFile, then I edit it and then I save it again to the StorageFile using the following code:

```
using (var writeStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    xDocument.Save(writeStream, SaveOptions.None);
}
```

However, when I make the contents shorter, eg from

```
<Node>
    <Child>This is a verrrrrryyy long text</Child>
<Node>
```

to

```
<Node>
    <Child>This is short</Child>
<Node>
```

The result on disk is as follows:

```
<Node>
    <Child>This is short</Child>
<Node>rrryyy long text</Child>
<Node>
```

Obviously the Stream writes only the the new bytes in the file, leaving the old ones intact thus resulting in an invalid XML the next time I try to open it, so this is probably not the right way to save...

How should I be saving it?

Comment: Do you de-serialise the data when you read it?

Comment: Code when i read the StorageFile:
`XmlDocument xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(storageFile);`
`XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlDocument.GetXml());`

Comment: I would reccommend you look into Serialization & Deserialization at the following link :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx I've nothad any problems like you have here doing things this way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm not reading/writing a class that is Serializable, just an xml.

Any clues on how to save it in that scenario?

Comment: SOLUTION is to truncate the stream:
`using (var writeStream = await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    if (writeStream.CanSeek && writeStream.Length > 0)
        writeStream.SetLength(0);
                        
    _xml.Save(writeStream, SaveOptions.None);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION is to truncate the stream:

```c
using (var writeStream = await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()) 
{ 
   if (writeStream.CanSeek && writeStream.Length > 0) 
      writeStream.SetLength(0); 
   _xml.Save(writeStream, SaveOptions.None); 
}
```